# Protobuf Tcp socket communcation with android

Tags: java, android, tcp, protocol-buffers, proto

So we have a c++ server which send profobuf messages to a android client.
I need to receive the message via tcp and change the ui on android.
The message is always the same.
So far i have this

```
{class ListenerThread extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
    Activity activity;
    IOException ioException;

    @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.N)
    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        Log.i("Do Background", "Background task started");
        while (true) {
            try {
                fromServer = socket.getInputStream();
                int nRead;
                byte[]data = new byte[1024];
                ByteArrayOutputStream buffer= new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                while((nRead=fromServer.read(data,0,data.length))!=-1){
                    buffer.write(data,0,nRead);
                }

                AppControlsProtos.LawnmowerStatus lawnmowerStatus = AppControlsProtos.LawnmowerStatus.parseFrom(data);

                Log.i("Waiting for msg ", "Waiting for messages started");
                 Methode 2
              CodedInputStream cis = CodedInputStream.newInstance(socket.getInputStream());
               AppControlsProtos.LawnmowerStatus lawnmowerStatus = AppControlsProtos.LawnmowerStatus.parseFrom(cis);


                handleStatus(lawnmowerStatus.getStatus());
                handleMowingErrors(lawnmowerStatus.getError());
                socket.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
```

}
So how i can read from a socket, handle with protobuf and do something with my protobuf message.

Comment: It looks as if the server is closing the socket after having sent a message?

Comment: `ByteArrayOutputStream buffer= new ByteArrayOutputStream();` To make your code better readable please change to `ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();`

Comment: `AppControlsProtos.LawnmowerStatus lawnmowerStatus = AppControlsProtos.LawnmowerStatus.parseFrom(data);` That is a strange construct as that data buffer does only contain part of a message.

            `

Comment: `fromServer = socket.getInputStream();` Why isn't `fromServer` a local variable? And why dont you name it intputSteam for better readability?

Comment: oh yes i already deledet  socket.close() but still doesnt work, 
i guess the problem is  AppControlsProtos.LawnmowerStatus lawnmowerStatus = AppControlsProtos.LawnmowerStatus.parseFrom(data); 

 We get bytes from the server but we cant make bytes to protobuf.

Comment: ???? I asked if the server closed the socket after having sent a message. As your receiving code expects the server to do so.

Comment: `We get bytes from the server but we cant make bytes to protobuf.`. Again: you are using that small byte array `data`. But then you have only a few bytes. All the bytes are in `baos`. You should use `baos` as it contains the whole message.

Comment: No the server doesnt closed the socket,

Comment: You mean: the server does not close the socket after having send a message. But then you will never get a -1 for nRead in nRead=inputStream.read().

Comment: `Log.i("Waiting for msg ", "Waiting for messages started");
                 Methode 2` ?? Confusing. If you tried in two ways then post two complete doInBackground() functions.

Comment: Yes we already discovered that problem , sorry im so frustated , we are trying to get this right for so long i`m really desperate,

Comment: Such things can happen sadly. Please adapt your code and post in the ways i suggested. Concentrate first on receiving a complete message. When you can do that the next problem is handling that message. But that is something completely different.

Comment: I have no idea what the server sends if it sends a protobuf in bytes. Can you give an example? Maybe we can adapt the approach.

Comment: Ok but how do i know the length of the message, i read somewhere that the server should send the length of the message.

Comment: Yes indeed. That is the normal way. The server first sends the length of the message and then the message itself. The client first reads the length and then reads as much bytes as the length. On the server the length is an integer variable. The server first sends that integer. That will be four bytes. The client first reads four bytes and converts them to an integer variable.

Comment: `Ok but how do i know the length of the message` It is unclear if you dont know at server side or client side or both.

Comment: Such a leading ineger indicating the length of the following message is not needed if the server would send plain text. But ... yea... i have no idea what the server sends ... you did not tell...